# HTML element's textContent and value unnecessarily different

Tags: javascript, html, w3c

Let's have, say, an element with the text content of `Clark, Theodore  S.`. Note the double white spaces after the "Theodore". Say you have this element be an HTML option, like this: `<option>Clark, Theodore  S.</option>`. If you try to extract its text content, you would correctly get the result `Clark, Theodore  S.`. However, if you try to get the option's `value` property, you get `Clark, Theodore S.`.

As per [MDN's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace), white spaces are often times ignored when formatting the DOM. However, wouldn't it be logical to have the `textContent` property return the trimmed value and the `value` property return the exact value? As far as I know, when you get the `value` of an input element no trimming is performed, so why is it done here?

Why is the `value` property modified in any way when it is expected that it would most accurately reflect the actual value set? Is this a bug in JavaScript or is it explicitly intended?

Comment: Incidentally, the double spacing has also been removed from your post except where you use backticks. You may want to edit your post to use backticks everywhere you have double space

Comment: @mikabytes you are correct, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: It looks like that the option elements in your markup don't have `value` attribute. If that's the case, the option elements are not a part of the datalist, and the value is "_Text that is not inter-element whitespace_". See [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-option-element). You can fix the issue by adding `value` attributes to `option` elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because in the absence of a `value` attribute, the `.text` value is used as the `<option>`'s value.
From the specs for [`HTMLOptionElement.prototype.text`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#dom-option-text)

> The `text` IDL attribute, on getting, must return the result of [stripping and collapsing ASCII whitespace](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#strip-and-collapse-ascii-whitespace) from the concatenation of [data](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-cd-data) of all the `Text` node descendants of the `option` element, in tree order, excluding any that are descendants of descendants of the `option` element that are themselves `script` or `SVG script` elements.

Thanks to this, we can write stuff like the following and still have the value `foo bar` being sent to the server as is likely expected.

```js
const el = document.querySelector("option");
console.log(el.text, el.text === el.value);
console.log(el.textContent);
```

```html
<select>
  <option>
    foo
    bar
    <script>
    // Something
    </script>
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Do we have any explanation why the `textContent` is exempt from this behavior then? I would assume it to also trim the extra white spaces, but strangely enough it returns them all.

Comment: Hard to say, it's just what it does. `textContent` returns the concatenation of all the descendant Text nodes `data`. No trimming, no filtering. Note that `textContent` is a DOM property, while `HTMLOptionElement` and its `.text` and `.value` props are defined by HTML. In that sense, the former is more "global" and generalist. (Also, it's not going to be sent through a `<form>` for instance, form the top of my head, I'd say it's only accessible through scripting.

Answer (score 2):

The `textContent` of a [HTMLOptionElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) is *not*  its value per se. Its value is/should be defined by its *value attribute*. If no value attribute is present, the text content is taken and apparently that content is cleaned up.

from the MDN link above:

> [Option.value] A string representing the value of the HTMLOptionElement, i.e. the value attribute of the equivalent . If this is not specified, the value of text is used as the value, e.g. for the associated  element's value when the form is submitted to the server.

If you need the exact value without a value attribute, `innerText` or `textContent` or `innerHTML` may be the alternative. Here's a comparison:

```js
const opt = new Option(`hello     <i>world</i>`)
console.log(`*opt*\nvalue: ${
  opt.value}\ntextContent: ${
  opt.textContent}\ninnerText: ${
  opt.innerText}\ninnerHTML ${
  opt.innerHTML}`);
  
const opt2 = new Option(`hello     <i>world</i>`, `hello     <i>world</i>`);
console.log(`*opt2*\nvalue: ${
  opt2.value}\ntextContent: ${
  opt2.textContent}\ninnerText: ${
  opt2.innerText}\ninnerHTML ${
  opt2.innerHTML}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Correct, however take note that the value attribute is **not** accurate. In this particular case the `textContent` retains the two white spaces correctly, while the `value` does not. Shouldn't it be the opposite? Furthermore, I'd argue the case that both white spaces should be returned in both cases.

Comment: I'm with you. Let's call it a quirk ;)